# Test Error - Observable - Angular 2 Unit Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am not getting any clue how shall i cover error scenario in my angular2 unit test case.

Below is my method

```
completeCall(body): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(URL, body, {
            headers: this.headers,
            withCredentials: true
        }).map(
            (results) => {
                return results.json();
            }).catch(
            (error: Response) => {
                this.router.navigate(['home']);
                return Observable.throw(error);
            });
    }
```

I have successfully covered success scenario but not sure about error scenario, How shall i cover that?

I have tried like below but
**No Luck**

```
mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
                const options: any = new ResponseOptions({
                    body: { error: 'Some strange error' },
                    status: 404
                });
                const response: any = new Response(options);
                connection.mockError(response);
            });
            spyOn(console, 'error');
            completeTradeService.completeTrade(requestData).subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res); // Object{error: 'Some strange error'}
            }, e => {
                expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith('404 - Some strange error');
            });
```